# Rails acceptance testing without using rspec but using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for an example of acceptance testing in Rails without using rspec. My current client uses ruby 1.9.2 and all the tests are written using minitest and they are concerned about the slowness of rspec. Anyways that discussion is over.

I need to write a few functional tests and am looking for examples of how to do functional tests without using rspec. And I would  like to use capybara.

I am using Rails 3.0.10 .

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to be looking at Cucumber - http://cukes.info/ perhaps?

Comment: Thanks but not really. One of the main concerns is speed so we want to  be away from cukes.